# React - State resets to an empty array inside UseEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, socket.io, react-hooks

I'm playing around with Socket.io but I can't figure out why my 'messages' state always returns an empty array when inside useEffect.

I would have expected when I call 'setMessages' it would update 'messages' from an empty array to an array with a new object.

And the the second time socket.on('message') is called state would then have one object inside the array and when I call setMessages again it would push a second object on to it.

But it appears to be always empty, any ideas?

Thanks

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Array<Message>>([]);
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('user connected');
    socket.on("message", (message: Message) => {
      console.log(messages); // This is always an empty array
      setMessages([...messages, message]); // But here I set the state to a copy of the state plus 'message' which is an object with an id and message property.
    });
  });
}, [messages]);
```

Comment: you probably dont want to update it like this. every time you get a message it runs the whole shebang. you're creating memoryleaks and nothing lives long enough...

Comment: first, remove the dependency (and put a cleanup on return) and then... well... thats probably it actually

Comment: I find this guide a nice intro to using sockets within React. https://levelup.gitconnected.com/handling-socketio-rooms-with-react-hooks-4723dd44692e

Comment: It includes also a memory leak where you disconnect your socket when your component unloads or the effect runs..

Comment: Thanks Noriller, I followed this guide:https://dev.to/otamnitram/react-useeffect-cleanup-how-and-when-to-use-it-2hbm but that doesn't seem to fix the empty array issue.

Also thanks @ChristianMoen I'll read the socket.io guide I wasn't sure if it was just a hooks mistake I was making or socket.io related.